# How do I fix randomly moved chunks after a crash?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was stupid and didn't keep a backup of my Minecraft server.  Now, it crashed, biomes changed, chunks were moved around, part of my city of gone, an underground chunk was moved aboveground, is there ANY way I can fix this?

I.E. easily move chunks and change biomes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They were moved because the map files got corrupt so it reads chunks in an out of place order.

It's like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 would turn into 1 0 4 6 7 8 9 0 0, where 0 would be unreadable thus deleted.

---

Picking a [known map editor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors#Map_Editors) should allow you to move chunks, they include terrain/forest generators.

*And set up an automated back-up solution...*

Comment: The only one I could get to work on linux spent about 10 minutes eating up all my RAM just to load a part of the world I had never seen before.  My machine slowed to a crawl and I didn't know which way to scroll in the editor because I didn't know which direction my city was.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well most of my city came back when I started it up again.  Although there is a chunk of rock sitting in the middle of it.  Also, that part the map editor loaded appears to be my new spawn point.  Lesson learned, backups made, I'm going to set up a cron job for that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @John: Best is to just get yourself a small Windows partition (dunno if virtualized graphics will run smooth enough) to fix this on, perhaps on another computer if that's available to you.

Comment: Well it appears that any attempt to get rid of the giant chunk of rock just makes the problem worse.  I blew up the chunk and the server wouldn't even start again.  Good thing I have backups *now*.  :P  I guess I'll just move it to a windows computer.

Comment: @John Don't get rid of it! Turn it into a shrine and worship it!

Comment: Well I moved it to a Windows computer and used MCEdit to delete the giant chunk of rock.  I pulled it up in singleplayer and there were hundreds of sheep, but it loaded the world.  When I tried to put the map back on my server, it wouldn't even load.  Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible with an already corrupted world? (fortunately, my players unanimously decided they wanted a new map anyway, but I want to learn as much as I can from this debacle)

Comment: @John: You need to do more analysis rather than a debacle, what would have happened if you loaded this up in SMP first? Would it work then? Did SP broke it? I think it did, but don't know the details...

Comment: I've moved maps from SP to MP before, and nothing has ever broke before...  Fortunately, I still have a copy of it before it was opened in SP, so I will try it.

Comment: Just tested.  It's definitely modification to the magic rock that breaks it.

Comment: @John: The magic rock chunk could be corrupted by itself, which is the only reason why I would think it would break. This needs modification at the file level, but I don't know exactly how that works. Or you could look for an alternative tool to delete a specific chunk, a quick search yields the interesting [MapDeleter](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/24389-mc-mapdeleter-pine-tree-generator/) although I wonder if you could figure out the rock on it's small size...

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for a fix:

1. Download and open Mcedit
2. Open your world using this program.
3. Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
4. Click `fix regions`.

Comment: Care to explain what control+I does?

Comment: Opens World Info dialog which contains repair button.

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup your world by copying the folder (either in operating system users folder or wherever you keep your minecraft server executables).
2. Close Minecraft single player game or server to avoid world corruption.
3. Download and open MCedit 1.3 (at the time of this writing, MCedit 2.0 alpha is not in good shape).
4. Open your world in MCedit.
5. Select problem chunks and **DELETE** them. They'll respawn *in their original state* when you log onto the world again.
6. Once you're sure you've deleted those problem chunks (and only those), save & exit.
7. Start your server / single player game up again. You should be ready to roll.