# How can I copy part of a Minecraft world into another Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[Backstory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27461/5029)

The places that have been built on in my world aren't that big.  It's a ~100x~100 square, a ~150x~50 rectangle in the Nether, and another ~100x~100 square accessed by portals.

The world is currently unplayable due to the server console spending so much time printing errors that the players time out. That, and for some reason it decided to spawn *hundreds* of sheep.

So I was wondering, is it was possible, and if so how, to move sections of this world into another, new, world?

Comment: I may be wrong, but MAYBE the biome information is not saved together with the chunks. I read about that here: http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/store_biomes_as_part_of_the_chunk_data (but that info might be outdated, I don't know). — Well, I asked about this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27634/where-are-biomes-saved-in-minecraft

Comment: @Denilson I am fairly certain that biomes are saved separate from the chunks because I have had biomes changed.

Comment: Pasting into a different map will almost certainly result in a biome mismatch. This may mean your desert in your old map is now tundra, and while the terrain will stay the same, it may snow...

Comment: @John I have the same problem with my minecraft world! It's not running as a server, only at home on my local PC and my favorite and giant world is not accessible anymore. One time I managed to move my character with an lvl editor and I saw hundreds of cows. It would be a pity if I had to give up this world. Did you manage to save your world with fredley's proposal?

Comment: @Exa I didn't try. Knowing that the biomes would never be the same, I decided to just start a new map. In your case however, if you have the original seed (I can help you get the current seed, but if it has changed you will still have a biome mismatch), then you can create a world with that seed and copy your other world in. That will guarantee a biome match because both worlds were generated from the same seed. I don't have my original seed, so that wouldn't have worked for me.

Comment: @John The seed should be the same, I think. I will try to extract the seed and create a new world and copy my old world into this world. My huge and beautiful mine :(

Comment: @Exa If you need, I can help you get the seed. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-173/). You can copy the section in your old map, and save it as a schematic, which you can then import and place into a new world (generated with Minecraft by starting a new game), overwriting what was there before. Make sure Minecraft is closed while you are using MCEdit, otherwise you can corrupt your map.

Comment: Do you have to copy the saved chuncks into another existing world, or can you save the selectioned chuncks of your old world, that you want to keep, and generate a new "world" around it? What I mean: Cutting a part of the old map out, keep this, and delete the rest, so that there will generate new/unused biomes around it? Greets and thank. :)

Comment: There is a `prune` operation on `mcedit` which will remove all chunks except the selected ones.

Comment: Personally I prefer Worldedit. It can perform most MCEdit operations, but from in-game. Also, it exists for Forge, Bukkit and more mod systems.

Comment: MCEdit is long dead unfortunately. NBTExplorer can do things like this but is also rapidly aging and is incompatible with Minecraft 1.16+ as of this writing. I have, however, found MCASelector just recently and am going to be using it later, it seems to be frequently updated to this day. I'll follow up if I have success with it. Github link: https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector

Answer (score 2):

Got a [<s>server</s>](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit) copy of Minecraft with Forge installed?

If you want to copy a region of your world, you can now just use [MCEdit](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit).

1. Open the world you wish to extract something from.
2. `//wand` to get a <s>wooden axe</s> tool wand to select your region.
3. <kbd>LMB</kbd> and <kbd>RMB</kbd> (first and second point) the tool wand on the blocks marking the cuboid you wish to extract.
4. `/schematic save [-f] <filename>` to save your region to a `.schematic` file.
5. Exit out and open the other world you wish to put things into.
6. `/schematic load <filename>` to load your exported area (from Step 4) to the clipboard.
7. Stand in the location you wish to place your structure in and then type `//paste`.

If you made a mistake (ie. stood in the wrong corner without wanting to deal with the hassle of [rotating](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/clipboard/)), you can just `//undo` and `//redo` your action. [See the official documentation for more info](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/commands/#schematic-and-clipboard-commands).

---

If you want to just copy whole chunks at a time, you [Querz/mcaselector](https://github.com/Querz/mcaselector) allows you to do just that.