# Can I alter the biome of an area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In part 3 of [my](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27461/5029) [adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27622/5029), I would like to find out if there is a way to change biomes.

In [part 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27622/5029), [fredley said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27622/how-can-i-copy-part-of-a-minecraft-world-into-another-minecraft-world/27623#27623) that it *is* possible to move terrain from one world to another, but the biomes wouldn't match.

Is there any way I can change the biome of a specific area to, say, [Savanna](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biomes#Biome_Types)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Minecraft 1.2 is released, using the new “Anvil” file format, biomes will be stored in the chunk data so that they can be redefined on a per-column (x,z) basis. You will need an editor which supports doing so, or a generic NBT editor, of course. ([Source](http://www.mojang.com/2012/02/14/new-minecraft-map-format-anvil/))

Comment: I know that the first answer is technically correct right now, but this one should be the accepted one, as it will be true come 1.2 release (I'd imagine quite soon).

Comment: 1.2 is expected first week of March 2012 last I heard...

Comment: @Eric You cannot change biomes *now in the current release version* of Minecraft.  When/if 1.2 releases and this answer becomes true, I will still be around to move the checkmark.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is now obsolete, please see [Kevin Reid's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/52572/11089) for current information.

---

According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27634/where-are-biomes-saved-in-minecraft), biomes are dependent on the level seed stored in the world. So, it means that, for every chunks, biomes are not saved in the chunk, but regenerated each time. You only chance a changing a biome would be to change the seed, but it would change every biome on the map, and new chunks won't match the old ones.

Comment: Can you update this? Since Anvil Format was introduced, biomes are saved in the chunk.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.2 introduced the [Anvil Format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_file_format), [WorldEdit](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/worldedit/) (either [SP](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Installation/Single_player) or via [bukkit](http://www.bukkit.org)) provides the [`//setbiome` command](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference) to change the biome directly in-game.

For bukkit, there is also [BioMed](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/biomed/), which I have not used - it seems to offer some features WorldEdit doesn't, like *"Convert whole maps to the same biome!"* and *"Spawn nether mobs in a normal world!"*

For out-game: the [MCEdit FAQ](https://github.com/mcedit/mcedit/wiki/FAQ) states

> #### Can I use MCEdit to edit the weather/biomes/temperature/snowfall?
>
> Currently, you can't. The new Anvil format does store biome data in the region files now, however, so the ability to do so will be added in a future version. Otherwise you can change the random seed, but that has other side effects.

However, [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1221526-mc-edit-how-to-change-biome-120512/) claims you can use [this MCEdit plugin](http://www.mediafire.com/?4r4b9ss8y1d73ne) to already modify the biomes, though I have not yet tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you must use a plugin called [WorldEdit](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/worldedit/). This will allow you to change the biome of a world chunk-by-chunk, using the `//setbiome` command.

The worlds you create will be compatible with vanilla Minecraft, so other people playing in your world will not need to have WorldEdit or any other mods installed for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.19.3, you can now use the /fillbiome command to do just that!

The format is: `/fillbiome ~ ~ ~ ~3 ~3 ~3 plains`

and you can optionally add "replace desert" (or something) at the end to only have it replace target biomes

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I just found.

I was using CMEdit to copy/paste creations from a couple of worlds into a superflat world, when I noticed this had pasted in the original biomes.  I copied a huge flat slab of grass from the superflat world and pasted it above the imported builds.  This altered the biome to "plains".  I then just filled the grass "roof" I had created with air.

It's all good now.  In the future, I'll just uncheck that little box marked "Copy Biome" before I paste stuff, but it's a happy accident.

So you still need MCEdit, but you can do without the plugin.

Hope this helps someone.