# How to stop winter? (Or, how to change a single biome in Minecraft / bukkit)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I alter the biome of an area?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27642/can-i-alter-the-biome-of-an-area)

After, copying my vanilla world to bukkit, the biome seems to have changed from tundra to snow (while the terrain is the same as I noticed by creating a new world with same seed). This means that there is a straight border between the tundra part of the world that I previously explored, and the snow land that bukkit generates now. It also causes WorldGuard to let my lake freeze since it is in a snow biome now.

Long story short: Is there any way to change the local biome back into tundra?

Comment: @JohntheGreen thanks, it is very closely related, but this is about the bukkit server which might offer this via a plugin. And as mentioned, I'd basically just want bukkit to use the same biome the vanilla server did

Comment: That still falls under my question.  I ask for "*any way*" to change a biome.  Anyway, if you've got the seed from the world you want it to act like, it should be quite easy.

Comment: @JohntheGreen well in that case you might be interested in [BioMed](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/biomed/) which I just found and am going to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this as biome data is not stored in the chunks.

In Minecraft snapshot 12w07a (i think it was this one), Jeb added a new world format which saves the biome data with the chunks. Because this snapshot is so new and the Minecraft Coder's Pack isn't released for the snapshots, there probably won't be a mod to allow this until Minecraft 1.2 is released.

I will update this answer if a tool to do this is ever released.