# How can I stitch Minecraft worlds together?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I visit a Minecraft survival multiplayer server. When monsters were added to SMP, the server archived the map and started afresh. When 1.8 is released, the server operator plants to do the same again.

I'd like to merge the old maps into locations the new map, at distant locations. Does a tool exist to stitch together entire maps like that?

Comment: There's a stiching tool now that I found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I copy part of a Minecraft world into another Minecraft world?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27622/how-can-i-copy-part-of-a-minecraft-world-into-another-minecraft-world)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My 1.8 plan is to allow players to select limited above ground areas that they would like to keep and then move those by hand to a fresh 1.8 map using [mcedit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-173/). In addition I'll set up a [portal](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tp-stargate-v0-6-6-the-bukkit-port-a-portal-plugin-1060.3927/) between worlds to allow them to move their other items like rails, torches, chests, etc by hand themselves if they want to.

I don't know of any "automated" stitching tools. Most people I've heard either do what I'm going to do, or just start with a fresh map and let their users move their own buildings.

**edit**

There is now a stiching tool.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/629884-a-tool-for-merging-171819-maps-mcmerge-v04/

Comment: MCEdit is what I used last time the world-generation mechanism changed (as it is certain to do in 1.8). It didn't look great at the time as it's just a big square of old terrain plonked in the middle of new, but as my site expanded the boundary became blurred.

Comment: Everything I've been building lately (at least mostly everything) keeps in mind the need of being able to be removed modularly and replaced somewhere else. I know I won't be able to move everything, especially some things like my underground mushroom farm, but I'll be able to get the bulk of it. The good thing is most of my players seem to be happier about getting a second shot (a lot of us are on this server as a first time SMP player) on a fresh server with all the materials we already need. =)

Comment: As stated in the question, I'd like to copy the entire map, not just pieces. I'd also like to place them very far from spawn in unexplored territory, like out past 1000,1000. Can MCEdit do this easily?

Comment: MCEdit requires that the area already be generated or "explored" so you have a few options here. You can explore manually, use teleports to explore or use a world generator (I don't know one offhand) to pregen a map that's the size you want. However if you're ok with keeping your current map exactly like it is, then you might be fine (depending on the update) with just updating your server to 1.8 when it comes out. All the areas outside your current map will be 1.8 areas and inside will be 1.7. Fair warning though, the "borders" between the versions will be rather hideous to look at. =/

Comment: I have tried mcedit and export of an entire world (862x862x256) does not work for me. Memory error.
My PC has 16gb ram and a 960gb ssd and 4.7ghz 8core. I think it might be a does limitation. Any other ideas

Answer (score 4):

As somebody with a lot of time and energy invested in Bigshell and the other maps you're referring to, I can confirm that MCEdit is exactly what you'll want. It's trivial to load the existing maps, select all of the terrain on which actual construction has occurred, and then export it to a file.

Once you've got files for each of the maps you want to incorporate, it's probably best to just start a new map in Creative mode and fly *way* out away from the spawn. You might want to survey a pretty big cross section of areas so you can find terrain that nobody's going to mind getting supplanted by the old content. While Kort Pleco states above that MCEdit requires the area to already be explored, the version I was using had some tools for filling in ungenerated sections, so it shouldn't be too hard to take a map that has some holes in it and import the files from above.