# How do I fix a corrupted world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I haven't got any backups, is there any way of recovering, or partially recovering the world from a corrupted save file?

Comment: If the first and best answer is to have backups, shouldn't that be an answer, rather than a part of the question? ♪

Comment: Corrupted world? Declare Exterminatus in the name of the Emperor and purge it with fire.

Comment: Wait, sorry, wrong game.  Maybe you could use a map editor and delete the corrupted portions of the map?  Also, this might help: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/119520-checkworldpy-corrupted-world-chunk-finder-to-be-updated/

Comment: Overthrow the bourgeoisie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix randomly moved chunks after a crash](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27461/5029)?

Comment: Use Purification powder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Originally found here](http://forums.fragnet.net/minecraft/545-repair-corrupt-world.html)

- copy & rename the server world folder into your solo save folder:

`C:\documents and settings\USERNAME\application data\.Minecraft\saves`

-or-

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves`

- Start & quit a new solo game
- Copy the .dat files from the new solo game into the corrupted world
- Start the corrupted world in solo mode to check
- copy the repaired world back to the server folder & rename
- If that doesn't work, try deleting the \players folder in that world as a last resort (player data will be lost)

Comment: And "player data will be lost", just to clarify, means **all** player data. Everything.

Comment: Unless you generate the exact same map, using one worlds level.dat for another world will result in a biome mismatch (meaning snowy deserts and the like). Unless you at least have your original seed, it is *impossible* to get your world back to its former state.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down - it fixed my world. The player data is intact. The biomes are the same, we had portals to 3 specific types.  Mind you, there are only two of us - but I wouldn't think that would have an impact.

Comment: This just saved me a weeks worth of tekkit work. Thank you so much I owe you...

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't the fix for me, but there's also a [Chunkster](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admin-chunkster.8186/) utility that will verify the world's region chunk files for corruption individually, if the problem happens to be in one of those.

Comment: Note: Chunkster has been deprecated since then.  It won't be useful for actual versions

Answer (score 3):

A useful tool that I've run into out there is something called [Minecraft Region Fixer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/302380-minecraft-region-fixer/) that may be able to help you solve your issue.

[Minecraft Region Fixer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/302380-minecraft-region-fixer/) is a command line-based tool that scans the files of a Minecraft world save and checks the file structures to see if there are corrupted chunks, or if there are other issues with the world save as well.

If you are not familiar with using a command line, it will be pretty easy if you read the author's documentation on his post. He does a good job of being clear and thorough, and hopefully you will be able to use it to solve your problem!