# How to reset randomly moved chunks in a Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I logged onto my 1.15.2 world one day, and all of the chunks in were out of place. I am aware that you can fix it by manually editing all the chunks back in place. But is there an alternative way to do that? Preferably via the code or one that's not so time consuming? I DO NOT want to RESET the chunks, just rearrange them back to where they are supposed to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix randomly moved chunks after a crash?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27461/how-do-i-fix-randomly-moved-chunks-after-a-crash)